# Return Custom Post Type Categories

Tags: custom-post-types, categories, custom-taxonomy

I have setup a custom post type within Wordpress. For this I have also registered a new taxonomy and added various categories. I then have assigned these to the posts, all of which works, it shows within the post edit etc.

How do I show these on the frontend? Whatever I try it does not work, its like wordpress doesn't know about them. Is there specific code to do this?

Comment: Can you share some of the code that you have tried so far?

Comment: Have you created a sample-post for the custom post type in the wp-admin? Where does the 'view post' link leads to?

Comment: Please post the code you used to register your post types & taxonomies. Also, could you clarify: What doesn't appear? Where specifically are you expecting to see it?

Answer (score 0):

When you add a custom taxonomy to a WordPress theme, you can display its content using one of [WordPress’ taxonomy theme templates](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy#Custom_Taxonomies_display)

- **taxonomy-{taxonomy}-{slug}.php** We could use this to create a theme
  template for a particular location, such as
  taxonomy-taxonomyname-termslug.php for the term “boston.”
- **taxonomy-{taxonomy}.php** If the taxonomy were location, WordPress
  would look for taxonomy-location.php.
- **taxonomy.php** This template is used for all custom taxonomies.
- **archive.php** If no taxonomy-specific template is found, then the
  taxonomy that lists pages will use the archive template.
- **index.php** If no other template is found, then this will be used.

Just make sure you set the post type  to your custom post type name on what ever template file you use.